# Creating conditional blocks in Invantive Composition for Word

Tags: ms-word, invantive-composition

How can I conditionally include/exclude sections of text in my Word document based upon contents of the database, e.g. I want to do something like this in a Microsoft Word document (pseudo code):

***IF <invantive:value-of expression="$P{Level}" /> GREATER THAN 3 THEN***

### TECHNICAL

#### Programming Languages

<invantive:foreach block="A.languages"><invantive:value-of expression="$F{technicalname}"/></invantive:foreach>

#### Operating Systems

<invantive:foreach block="B.systems"><invantive:value-of expression="$F{technicalname}"/></invantive:foreach>
***END***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to exclude the whole piece of text starting with `TECHNICAL` and ending at `END`, you can also add an additional block in the model which either returns 0 or 1 rows.

Return 0 rows when the criterium is not met, return 1 row when it is met:

```
select 'ignore' from dual where <BOOLEAN EXPRESSION>
```

Of course, you will need to replace `dual` by the corresponding singular table of the database platform used. On Oracle and Invantive SQL platforms, there is always a `dual`. On SQL Server you can skip the `from dual`. On other platforms, either create a table or query something known to only have one row, like a specific data dictionary table.

Then use the new block to create a nested foreach:

```
<invantive:foreach block="FILTERBLOCK">
TECHNICAL
Programming Languages
<invantive:foreach block="A.languages"><invantive:value-of expression="$F{technicalname}"/></invantive:foreach>
Operating Systems
<invantive:foreach block="B.systems"><invantive:value-of expression="$F{technicalname}"/></invantive:foreach>
</invantive:foreach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that the easiest way by putting the parameter check in a block. If possible, do that in the block that contains the data, or create an intermediate block to do so.

For example, put this in your query:

```
select ...
from   yourtable
where  $P{Level} > 3
```